# Pass a row ID from one section of the Page to another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like to pass an row ID from one section of the page to another in the following way:[image]

The user will click on the trash can and a delete confirmation message will come up.   The following code shows how I retrieve the list from the database:

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_set)) { ?>
<tr>

  <td><?php echo $row['cover_name'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo 'R '.$row['sum_insured'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['info'] ?></td>
  <td>
      <a href="cover-type.php?id=<?php echo $row['coverid']?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
      <a href="#myModal" onclick="<?php $coverid = $row['coverid'] ?>" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a><!-- This is the link for the trash can to pass the id -->
  </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

After clicking on the following `<a href="#myModal" onclick="<?php $coverid = $row['coverid'] ?>" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a><!-- This is the link for the trash can to pass the id -->`

The following pop will come up:

[image]
and it has the following code:

```
    <div class="modal small fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="error-text"><i class="fa fa-warning modal-icon"></i>Are you sure you want to delete the cover?<br>This cannot be undone.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
            <a href="delete-cover.php?id=<?php echo $coverid ?>" class="btn btn-danger"  >Delete</a><!-- I would like to pass the id from that trash can button this the delete button -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to pass the id from the trash can link to the delete button that pops up. Any assistance will be appreciated

Comment: if the id is in `$_GET['id']` on `delete-cover.php`, then it should be fairly straightforward, just process it.

Comment: The id does get to delete-cover.php, but only the id of last row. In this case the row containing Crime Lord

Comment: just use a `data-whatever-id` attribute, then get the value from there, then pass it on to the next, the href

Answer (score 0):

This is surely not good:

```
onclick="<?php $coverid = $row['coverid'] ?>"
```

It should be somethig like that:

```
onclick="jsfunctionname(<?php echo $row['coverid'];?>);"
```

Or if you use jQuery on selector, then add a `data-id="<?php echo $row['coverid'];?>"` to the link, and get like  `$(this).data('id');`

Comment: with this line onclick="<?php $coverid = $row['coverid'] ?>" I managed to pass the id to the delete button, but only the id of the last row gets passed.